# Possible to add a form into another models view in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a very small application I ma building in rails. It is a simple weight tracker app. I have created a `User` model which has a sign up page. Once the user logs in they are redirected to the `user#show` view. Here is the user controller so far:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_user!

def show
  @user = current_user
end

end
```

I have 2 other models one is a `Weight` model and the other a `Goal` model, I would like it so what when a user signs up they are presented with a screen asking them to type in the current weight and goal weight this information will then be store in the `Weight` and `Goal` models respectively along with the logged in users ID.

So far I have been able to add a form to the user `show.html.erb` template :

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>

  <%= f.fields_for :weight do |builder| %>
    <fieldset>
      <%= f.label :value, "Current weight" %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :value %><br />
    </fieldset>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Which renders the form correctly but when I then click on the submit button it simply goes to an error page saying `Unknown action- The action 'update' could not be found for UsersController`. Im assuming iM doing something wrong as it should try and send to the create action.

Is there anyone out there who could help me back on the right path, Im very much a noob at rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `form_for` Rails helper and passing `@user` to it, because `@user` is a persistent model (saved in the db) then the generated form will have the action to `/users/:id` with `PUT` method so the request will be sent to an action named `update` in your `UsersController`, it seems that you don't have that action defined in your `UsersController`

it should be somthing like the following:

```
def update
  @user = Users.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
  # do something if saving succeeds
  else
  # do something if saving fails
  end
end
```

Comment: Oh right I see so how would it be best to insert the weight and goal value into their respective tables?

Comment: I just added in that code and received the following error:
`{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"ciFbrD782Q+fS9h8gSZxHD2fEBlWoTVFTT2asHhcpPQ=",
 "user"=>{"weight"=>{"value"=>"1.5"}},
 "commit"=>"Update User",
 "id"=>"1"}`

It seems like it trying to save the value content of the weight model into the user table. How dod i do it so that it saves to its own table.

Comment: as @Khaled said, you create an instance variable @user to save to User table. Same thing can be done to the others, Weight, Goal etc.I would do it using a custom hash instead ie `@weight.update_attributes({:value1 => params[:user][:value1],:value2 => params[:user][:value2]})`

Answer (score 2):

Well this has nothing to do with all your models. This pertains to the fact you have not defined an `update` method in your controller.

When you have done that look into [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) if you want to nest models.

Besides all that, a `show` page *usually* shows a read only for of the object. An `edit` page has the editable form of the object.

Comment: Would it be better then to create another controller called for example dashboard and use the index action to have this form? I was basically trying to keep it as minimal as possible.

Comment: In that (and almost any other) case: think 1 page, 1 model.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, after searching for this question having similar issues, that it is not update that is missing but edit.

I know this is an old thread, and you have probably solved the issue, but if not try adding this:

```
def edit

    @user = User.find(params[:id])

end
```