# Trouble with Rails ActiveRecord relationships and adding a record for one model within another models view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, activerecord

I put all the code in this gist because I can't get the formatting to work.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/72e66308c236a0277943

What I am trying to do is to have a form for the prof_comments model on the Professors page.

Whenever I try and submit the form I currently have for the prof_comments model, it tries to post to the current professors show page (/professors/1)

I've been trying to follow the following StackOverflow posts, but no luck yet.

[Rails: Show form from different model in a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188999/rails-show-form-from-different-model-in-a-view)

[Possible to add a form into another models view in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098036/possible-to-add-a-form-into-another-models-view-in-rails)

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  root :to => "welcome#index"
  devise_for :users
  resources :users

  resources :professors
  resources :prof_comments
  resources :classes
  resources :class_comments

end
```

Comment: so you want the prof_comments to appear under the professor's `show page`? Like a post and a nested comments? please explain more. also, post your `routes.rb`

Comment: Yes, I want to have a form to add a new prof_comment for that professor under its show page. I just added routes.rb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the approach you were trying but this will do exactly what you are trying to do: have the professor's comments appear under it's `show` page.

You can nest `prof_comments` under `professors`

your routs will look like this:

```
resources :professors do 
   resources :prof_comments, shallow: true
end
```

`prof_comments controller`:

```
 def create 
    @professor = Professor.find(params[:id]) #this pulls specific professor by :id
    @prof_comment = @professor.prof_comments.create(prof_comment_params)
    redirect_to professor_path(@professor) # this will rout you to professor's show page once the comment is created. 
    end
 end
```

in `app/views/professors/show.html`

```
 h2>Add a comment:</h2>
  <%= form_for([@professor, @professor.prof_comments.build]) do |f| %>

   <%= f.label :commenter %><br> #commenter with the actual attribute_name
   <%= f.text_field :commenter %> #commenter with the actual attribute_name

   <%= f.label :body %><br> #body should be replaced with your actual attribute_name
   <%= f.text_area :body %> #body should be replaced with your actual attribute_name

   <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

these comments will appear under the `professor show` view. the comments are nested under it. Treat the professor's controller as usual. you'll be using to create the comments using `prof_comments` controller.

Comment: I'll have to try both out. I think I am going to accept yours now since it looks like it is more fleshed out. IT also looks like it concentrates more on linking it all together. Thanks!

Comment: btw, you can move the comment form to a partial and render it to avoid clutter. and by the way, this approach is from the [rails guides tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html). it will walk you through it

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
form_for @prof_comment
```

with @ not :

Comment: I think I understand. The @prof_comment means I'm referencing that prof_comment instance I defined in the controller under the show route?

Comment: Good explanation here of the difference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006329/ruby-on-rails-symbol-as-argument-in-form-for

Comment: Ok. So it looks like my next problem is going to be to send the professor id to the prof_comments controller. This is gonna be fun.

Comment: You can use `hidden_field_tag 'professor_id', 1` then you get the professor_id in `params[:professor_id]`